# recommended maximum dataset size for Apache Jena

Tags: jena

I would like to know what is currently the maximum dataset size supported by Apache Jena (https://jena.apache.org/index.html). For example is it suited for datasets in the order of 100 million, 1 billion or 20 billion triples?

Thank you
D063520

Comment: There is no internal limit in that range. The current loaders for TDB2 will load 1billion+ and there is a new loader in the next release that's better loading 1billion+ on modest hardware and rotating disk.  But it's not just data scale. The query patterns matter - analytics queries are not the same as information retrieval queries.

Comment: Could you detail this a bit more. What would be the hardware requirements for a 10-20 billion triple graph? How much would be the indexing time? I'm thinking of wikidata here!

Comment: I haven't loaded wikidata - I don't have access to the separate hardware. But I guess several days.